# Difference between :d and dd in vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a difference between <kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>+<kbd>CR</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in normal mode in vim?

It seems the former is an Ex command and they have the same effect.

Answer (score 7):

There are some commands that are only in visual mode, and some commands only in ex mode; but there are some commands in both.  Deleting a line is in both.

In visual mode, you make up a command with three possible parts: a count, a command, and what the command should operate upon.  The basic delete command is `d`, and you can combine it with movement commands: move to next word is `w`, delete to next word is `dw`; move to next paragraph is `}`, delete to next paragraph is `d}` and so on.  As a special shortcut, `dd` deletes a line.  You can delete three lines with `3dd`.  But note that there are many, many ways to delete part of a line.

In ex mode, the delete command can only operate on whole lines.  You can prefix the delete command with line numbers to delete a range of lines: `:1,10d<Enter>` would delete lines 1 through 10.  You can mark a line with mark `b` and mark another line with mark `e` and then delete from the one to the other like so: `:'b,'ed<Enter>`  And you can delete the current three lines by following `d` with a count: `:d3<Enter>`

In ex mode, to operate within a line you need to use the `s` command (substitute).  To change *hamburger* to *hot dog* you would use: `:s/hamburger/hot dog/<Enter>`

In a sense, ex mode came first.  The first editor was called `ed` and `ex` was a super-set of the features of `ed`, and then added visual editing.

Answer (score 5):

With `:d`, you can add an integer after it to specify how many lines to delete. With `dd`, you delete one line only.

For example, using `:d3` will delete three lines; of course, if you just use `:d` with no number following it, there is no difference.

EDIT: Thanks to steveha and BenjaminRH for clarifying below - it turns out you can delete using `dd` by using a number *before* it. You can also repeat `dd` by using a `.`.

Comment: You can type an integer before `dd` to specify how many lines to delete.

Comment: Ahh didn't know that. Not sure where exactly the difference is then, other than ordering...

Comment: Also, `dd` can be repeated with `.`

Comment: Thanks - gotta love how there's always something new to learn about vim :-)